# Laravel artisan queue:work redirect stderr/stdout to file

Tags: bash, laravel-5, stdout, stderr, laravel-artisan

I'm trying to redirect the `stdout` and `stderr` of command `php artisan queue:work` while it's in background. 
To accomplish this, I've created this script :

```
## script name: queue_work.sh

    #!/bin/bash

    ## Redirect Files

    STDOUTFILE="${RootDir}/storage/logs/queue_output"
    STDERRFILE="${RootDir}/storage/logs/queue_error"

    ## Run php artisan

    php ${ARTISANCMD} queue:work --queue=high --sleep=3 --tries=3 1>"${STDOUTFILE}_high.log" 2>"${STDERRFILE}_high.log" &
    php ${ARTISANCMD} queue:work --queue=low  --sleep=3 --tries=3 1>"${STDOUTFILE}_low.log" 2>"${STDERRFILE}_low.log" &
```

When I run

```
./queue_work.sh
```

the four files are well created into `storage/logs/` and when I process `Queueable` the queue works well (that is process the commands) all `queue_output*.log` and `queue_error*.log` files stay empty.

What doesn't work in my simple script?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try running

```
nohup php artisan queue:work
```

it will create nohup.out file where all the output and errors will be displayed like:

```
[2017-03-24 00:00:00] Processed: App\Jobs\SomeJob
```